# extend CruiseControl.NET session duration

Tags: session, cruisecontrol.net, duration

I can't make CC to extend my session time , 10 minutes by default! I've tried extending session duration both with in memory and file based cache, but it seems that nothing helps.

I'm using version 1.9.48.0 because of multi source control for svn support.

this is what I've tried:

```
<internalSecurity>
<cache type="inMemoryCache" duration="300" mode="sliding" />
or
<cache type="fileBasedCache" duration="100" mode="sliding" location="C:\ccnet\sessions\" />
...
</internalSecurity>
```

Comment: Can you try increasing upto 60. It seems to work up until 60 for me.  - inmemorycache

Comment: Have you increased the session timeout in IIS?

Comment: <internalSecurity>
<cache type="inMemoryCache" duration="600" mode="sliding"/>
<audit>
<xmlFileAudit/>
</audit>
<auditReader type="xmlFileAuditReader"/>

&lt;cb:include href="securityUsers.xml"/&gt;
    &lt;cb:include href="securityPermissions.xml"/&gt;

&lt;defaults forceBuild="Allow" startProject="Deny" sendMessage="Deny" changeProject="Deny" modifySecurity="Deny" viewProject="Deny" defaultRight="Deny"/&gt;
  &lt;/internalSecurity&gt;

Answer (score 0):

If cruise control is throwing this exception

> "ThoughtWorks.CruiseControl.Remote.CommunicationsException: Request
>   processing has failed on the remote server: The session token is
>   either invalid or is for a session that has expired."

it might be the IIS session. I would try decreasing the duration to 60 and checking session timeout settings in IIS.

In IIS, sometimes the session timeout is configured properly for top level container, but the lower or bottom level container still has a default value and overrides the value in top level container. So, you can try [configuring session timeout](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725820%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in all the containers (the server, site and the actual web site) in the tree on left hand panel in IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the inMemoryCache duration between 0-60 minutes.. I don't think 300 is a valid value here.. The range seems to be between 0-60.